# How to sort main array using a child array (Android)

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, kotlin

I want to sort my main array using a child array value. Output as below:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "statusCode": 100,
  "message": "",
  "data": {
    "win": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "admin": [
          {
            "id": "38",
            "name": "Admin 05",
            "point": {
              "id": "96",
              "name": "96"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "admin": [
          {
            "id": "39",
            "name": "Admin 06",
            "point": {
              "id": "95",
              "name": "95"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "admin": [
          {
            "id": "26",
            "name": "Admin 05",
            "point": {
              "id": "98",
              "name": "98"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want array as below but I am not able to do so.

id = 3 // first

id = 1 // second

id = 2 // third and so on.

I tried below:

```
Collections.sort(loWinArray, object : Comparator<Win> {
                    override fun compare(obj1: Win, obj2: Win): Int {
                        // ## Ascending order
                        return (obj2.admin.get(0).point!!.name.toInt() - obj1.admin.get(0).point!!.name.toInt()) // To compare string values
                    }
                })
```

Can any one please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be sorted by the point ID, largest first to smallest last, try this:

```
val sortedArray = loWinArray.sortedByDescending { item -> item.admin.first().id.toInt() }
```

Comment: Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:197)
        at com.meapp.PanelManagerActivity$onCreate$$inlined$sortedByDescending$1.compare(Comparisons.kt:321)
        at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:234)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1432)
        at kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysJvmKt.sortWith(_ArraysJvm.kt:1737)

   
getting exception with this, list is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this for ascending order what you have tried it will return descending order

```
 Collections.sort(loWinArray, object : Comparator<Win> {
                        override fun compare(obj1: Win, obj2: Win): Int {
                            // ## Ascending order
                            return obj1.admin.get(0).point!!.name.toInt() - obj2.admin.get(0).point!!.name.toInt()
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.meapp.PanelManagerActivity$onCreate$5.compare(ManagerActivity.kt:142)
        at com.meapp.PanelManagerActivity$onCreate$5.compare(ManagerActivity.kt:139)
        at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)

Getting above exception

Comment: @Rara your list is empty

Comment: val test = ArrayList<String>()
        test.add("4")
        test.add("1")
        test.add("3")
        test.add("7")
        test.add("2")

        Collections.sort(test) { o1, o2 -> Integer.parseInt(o1) - Integer.parseInt(o2) }

        for (i in test.indices) {
            Log.e("Test => ", test[i])
        }